# How to find out if the key was pressed by a program or human?

Tags: java, windows, keyboard, key

I'd be interested in if is there any method to detect if the pressed key on the keyboard was pressed on the physical keyboard or if it was just typed with a program. Is there any way in Java to find it out?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I would doubt that there is a way as the PC itself interprets the signal from the keyboard and you are very likely not to have that deep of an access with java to intercept that path for any checks

Comment: Similarly I really doubt it would be possible. I probably won't be able to check it in any program (in Java or anything else) - that information is most likely lost on the level of keyboard drivers and OS don't care if it's physical or not. Just curious - how would you deal with a virtual keyboard? Is it "physical" for your needs?

Comment: It depends. If "typed with a program" is your's program I guess you could check the event source or wrap Event. Could you pls. give us more details what kind of problem you try to solve?

Comment: No, it is not typed with my program, I'm working on a program for my teacher to help reducing the cheating in homeworks. Our homework is to type to the computer some text that she gives us, but we shouldn't use scanners or things like that, because we need to practise fast typing with 10 fingers. And the program is done, but there are some programs that are able to simulate the key presses and I'm not sure if it is registered by keyPressedEvent, but I think it can be

Comment: Oh, ok. It is clear right now. It is serious security & platform dependent task so it is not an option.
What would I suggest in your case is random CAPTCHA.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA

Just insert it  in the text string the user has to type.